# Escape characters for an antlr lexer and parser

Tags: java, antlr

I am new to antlr and looking to build a parser, part of which requires me to match strings, however I am looking to preserve the meaning of escape characters

```
\0, \b, \t, \n, \f, \r, \", \', \\
```

Some of these symbols are used in various within the grammar of my language positions, hence I am looking to define an ESCAPE_CHAR token by:

```
SINGLE_QUOTE: '\'' ;
DOUBLE_QUOTE: '"' ;
ESCAPE_ZERO : '\0' ;
ESCAPE_BACKSPACE : '\b' ;
ESCAPE_TAB : '\t' ;
ESCAPE_NEWLINE : '\n' ;
ESCAPE_FORMFEED : '\f' ;
ESCAPE_CARRIAGERETURN : '\r' ;
ESCAPE_BACKSLASH : '\\' ;
ESCAPE_CHAR: ESCAPE_ZERO | ESCAPE_BACKSPACE | ESCAPE_TAB | ESCAPE_NEWLINE | ESCAPE_FORMFEED | ESCAPE_CARRIAGERETURN | DOUBLE_QUOTE | SINGLE_QUOTE | ESCAPE_BACKSLASH ;
```

However, ESCAPE_ZERO is giving me the warning

```
non-fragment lexer rule ESCAPE_CHAR can match the empty string
```

And when making ESCAPE_ZERO a fragment, I see the warning

```
invalid escape sequence \0
```

I am new to antlr so I don't really know what changes I need to make, any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `\` inside a literal in ANTLR as well. If you don't, the lexer rule `ESCAPE_ZERO : '\0' ;` matches the null character instead of a backslash followed by the zero digit. And this null character has no "width" which causes ANTLR to produce the error *[...] can match the empty string*.

Instead of all your separate rules, try something like this:

```
STRING
 : '"' ( ~[\\"\r\n] | ESCAPE_CHAR )* '"'
 ;

fragment ESCAPE_CHAR
 : '\\' [0btnfr"'\\]
 ;
```

Comment: Sorry @Bart, but I am still struggling, I added ```CHARACTER
 : ( ~[\\"\r\n] | ESCAPE_CHAR_ )
 ;

fragment ESCAPE_CHAR_
 : '\\' [0btnfr"'\\]
 ; ``` due to name clashes and then added the rule character: CHARACTER ;, and str_liter: DOUBLE_QUOTE character* DOUBLE_QUOTE ;

Comment: However, then when using the str_liter I get this e.g. (str_liter " hello ") with accompanying error line 2:9 extraneous input 'hello' expecting {'"', CHARACTER}

Comment: Sorry if that is too specific to my example, but I thought I took what you provided and adapted it appropriately

Comment: You should really not make `str_liter` a parser rule, but rather a lexer rule instead (as I showed in my example)

Comment: The reason I have it is because I require a char_liter rule which looks like ```char_liter: SINGLE_QUOTE CHARACTER SINGLE_QUOTE```. Any suggestions given that?

Comment: Also make `char_liter` a lexer rule.